# I got error, undefined offset 3, undefined offset 4, undefined offset 5

Tags: php

```
 $view_users_query="select * from messagetest where status='unread'";//select query for viewing users.  
        $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.  

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.  
        {  
            $id=$row[0];
            $invoice_no=$row[1];
            $date=$row[2];  
            $product_name=$row[3];
            $module_number=$row[4];
            $status=$row[5];  


        ?>
```

Comment: 0,1,2,3,4,5 are column names in database ? what are column names in your database ?

Comment: share `print_r($row);exit;` output ? inside while.

Comment: also last closing } is missing